# UITableViewController stops scrolling when navigated to from Login

Tags: uitableview, swift2, swift3

I am new to swift coding so hopefully this is nice and simple! :) I am navigating to a NavigationController with a segue identifier called "login_on" when my Login now button is pressed. I am using code:

```
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "login_on", sender: self)
```

When the Segue occurs, the UITableViewController that appears as the root of the NavigationController has content loaded inside via a JSON call as expected but then can't be scrolled and the buttons in the navigation can't be pressed either.

If I change the Initial View controller to skip the login and just load the NavigationController directly the scroll is working fine.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dumb moment had managed to add an ignoring interaction events line to the login code

```
UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
```

And then had commented out the switch off whilst I was testing the rest of the app....

```
UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
```

:D